# How to transform a list into a unique list?

Tags: java, list

So I have these two Classes, **ParentClass** and a **ChildClass** and I have these data(displayed on jTable):

```
Child Class       Parent Class
Child Class 1     Parent Class A
Child Class 2     Parent Class A
Child Class 3     Parent Class B
Child Class 4     Parent Class A
Child Class 3     Parent Class B
...               ...
```

From this **ChildClass View** I am trying to get all parent class and put it into a **Unique List/Set**, because i will create a summary for this by saying **Parent Class A has this total number of Child Class** and I am doing like this:

```
List<ParentClass> parents = new ArrayList<ParentClass>();
...
for(ChildClass child : childs){
    ParentClassDaoImpl parentClassDaoImpl = new ParentClassDaoImpl();
    ParentClass parent = parentClassDaoImpl.findParent(child.getParentId());
    if(parents.isEmpty()){
        parents.add(parent);
    }else{
        if(parents.indexOf(parent) == -1){//I have to check if this parent is already on my lists
            parents.add(parent);
        }
    }
}
...
```

My problem is that I always get a duplicate list. I tried this but i get same output:

```
...
if (!parents.contains(parent)) {
    parents.add(parent);
}
...
```

By the way I am using 1.6 Java Version.

Comment: Lists don't care about uniqueness. You could Implement equals & hashcode correctly and use a `Set` instead of a `List`.

Comment: Just implement hashcode and equals correctly and then use a set

Comment: We'd need to see your parent class but I suspect you didn't implement `equals()` or at least not correctly (and when implementing `equals()` you should not forget about `hashCode()`). Besides that if you want to have a _unique_ collection then use a set. If you want to collect additional info, e.g. the number of children, a map might be better.

Comment: You should use Set<ParentClass> parents = new HashSet<ParentClass>(); instead of List<ParentClass> parents = new ArrayList<ParentClass>();

Comment: share the parent class structure

Comment: Indeed you are all right, i was not able to include `equals(Object o)` method on my Parent Class. Thank you very much for it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a List maybe you could manage a `Map<ParentClass, Set<ChildClass>>` ?

The key of your map would be the parent class, and the value would be a set of its children.

So you would iterate over all the children, and for each, you would simply call something like `map.get(parent).add(child);`
Obviously before that, you will ensure that if the map does not contain that parent yet, you initialize its set of children with an empty set :

```java
if (!map.containsKey(parent)) {
   map.put(parent, new HashSet());
}
```

In the end, you can iterate over the map, and display the size of each value set, for each key ...

HTH !

Comment: I could try your solution, I think this can shortens my process of getting the total number of child class. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have tried your suggestions but I noticed something. It does not take all my Child Class. For example if in my actual data **there are 5 Child Class Under Parent Class A** upon running my program ** only 4 were printed**.

Comment: @AnirudhLou hard to answer without sample code. Maybe you forgot to add the first child, when you create the empty `HashSet` ?? Editing your post with the running answer would be nice for other people anyway!

Comment: `for(ChildClass child : childs){
    ParentClassDaoImpl parentClassDaoImpl = new ParentClassDaoImpl();
    ParentClass parent = parentClassDaoImpl.findParent(child.getParentId());
        if (!map.containsKey(parent)) {
            map.put(parent, new HashSet());
        }else{
           map.get(parent).add(child);}}

    for (Map.Entry<ParentClass, Set<ChildClass>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "\n " + entry.getValue() + " Total " + entry.getValue().size());
    }`

Comment: Your solution sir is better than mine, since mine has two for loop. One for the parent and one for the child. It just that it cannot take all the child class.

Comment: @AnirudhLou : it's not `if (!map.containsKey(parent)) { 
   map.put(parent, new HashSet()); 
  } else { 
   map.get(parent).add(child);
  }` ==> it should be `if (!map.containsKey(parent)) { 
   map.put(parent, new HashSet()); 
  } 
  map.get(parent).add(child);
  `

Answer (score 2):

Every time you get new object of ParentClass thats why when ever you check that object is present in the list or not is always says that not present because it compare with reference of the object.

for maintain unique list of object either overried `equels()` method or  just use `Map<ParentClass Id, ParentClass object>` and then just get `map.values()` method .